# Python subprocess pipe executes command before doing communicate()

Tags: python

I'm on python Python 2.7.6. Python subprocess pipe executes command before doing communicate(). I'm not even interested in output the result.

I'm testing, trying to achieve,

`$ echo date | at [timespec]`

What's wrong in my code?

```
In [2]: cmd = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'date'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

In [3]: future = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1)

In [4]: at = subprocess.Popen(['at', future.strftime("%H:%M %D")], stdin=cmd.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

In [5]: warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 11 at Sun Mar 13 16:31:00 2016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code, this is just how `Popen` works.

The creation of the process starts it.

The call to `process.communicate` just waits for it to finish.
See the docs:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html

> class subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=-1, executable=None, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, preexec_fn=None, close_fds=True, shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False, startupinfo=None, creationflags=0, restore_signals=True, start_new_session=False, pass_fds=())
>
> Execute a child program in a new process. On POSIX, the class uses os.execvp()-like behavior to execute the child program. On Windows, the class uses the Windows CreateProcess() function. The arguments to Popen are as follows.

And communicate:

> Popen.communicate(input=None, timeout=None)
>
> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.